# Maps between Spec of polynomial rings open and closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

I was looking for the $\mathbb{C}-$algebra maps $\varphi:\mathbb{C}[x]\to\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that the associated map $\varphi^\star:\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}[x,y]\to \text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}[x]$ are both open and closed.

I know that $\varphi^\star$ is closed if and only if $\varphi$ satisfies the Going Up property, so I was trying to study which maps have this property, but I didn’t conclude anything. I can describe the spectrum of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ (it is a PID, and since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed the prime ideals are $(0)$ and all of the form $(x-\alpha),$ $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$) and in a similar way at least a partial description of the spectrum of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (I have to consider the ideals of the form $(p(x,y)),$ where $p(x,y)$ is irreducible), but it seems to me I don’t get anything useful. I don’t know if the geometric point of view can be useful. Any hint?

Comment: *Hints:* (1) Find the closed subsets of $\text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]$.
(2) Show that both $\text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are irreducible topological spaces. (3) Show that $\phi^*(\text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x,y])$ is irreducible. This will give you sufficient hints about the image of $\phi^*$, and you can find $\phi$ accordingly.

Comment: I try to give an answer using the hints: 1) gives me that the non trivial closed subsets of $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}[x]$ are the finite unions of points of the form $\{(x-\alpha)\}$ (with $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$). 2) follows for example from the exercise 19), page 13, in Atiyah-MacDonald, and 3) follows from the fact that irreducibility is preserved from continuous maps. Now, $\phi^\star$ must be both open and closed, and in particular $\phi^\star(\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}[x,y])$ must be closed and irreducible, hence it is the whole space, or a point of the form $\{(x-\alpha)\}.$ Is it right?

Comment: Now, I observe that the only possibility is the first, since the points are not open subsets and the map $\phi^\star$ is open, too. Hence a necessary condition is that $\phi^\star$ must be surjective, right? But how can I get any information about $\phi?$

Comment: Form the surjectivity of $\phi^\star$ I get that $\phi$ is injective. But this is only a necessary condition and I don't conclude anything. I think such maps don't exist, but I don't see how to do it